# Como deixar todos os itens de um menu com tamanho igual independente da quantidade?

Tags: jquery, css3

Quero fazer um menu que deixe sempre os itens com tamanhos proporcionais, ocupando toda a largura disponível e adaptando-se.

```css
.top-menu ul {
  width: 100%;
}

.top-menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.top-menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu full">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Aqui!</a></li>
    <li><a>Alí!</a></li>
    <li><a>Acolá!</a></li>
    <li><a>Mais Pra lá</a></li>
    <li><a>Não sei onde</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pronto Sergio, restaurei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir isso você tem de dar `display: table;` ao `ul` e `display:table-cell;` ao `li`.

Teste assim:

```
.top-menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.top-menu ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    list-style: none;
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fnQ4W/1/)

Uma outra opção no caso de saber quantos `li` têm pode usar assim no `.top-menu ul li {`:

```
float: left;
width: 16%; // neste caso (100% / 6 links) = 16%
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fnQ4W/)

Answer (score 4):

Defina `display:table-cell;` para as li's, assim vão se comportar como cedulas de tabelas e consequentemente preencher todo o espaço disponível.

Answer (score -2):

Por que não tenta dinamicamente utilizando jQuery? Por exemplo, você pode obter o número de list itens em tempo de execução e dividir a largura total por esse valor, atribuindo o resultado para a largura de cada um dos ítens de sua lista, algo semelhante ao seguinte trecho de código:

```
var seletorDosItens = $(".top-menu full").find("li");
var totalDeItensDaLista = seletorDosItens.length;
seletorDosItens.css("width", (100 / totalDeItensDaLista) + "%");
```

Comment: Porém se o seu layout for responsivo, haverá problemas a menos que adicione eventos para atualizar conforme a mudança do viewport, e estes por sua vez, influenciariam em performance. Eu ainda recomendaria fielmente utilizar CSS.

Comment: Acho que pra mexer com estilização quanto mais css melhor.

Comment: Ulysses, seu código deu certo, só tive que retirar "full" de $(".top-menu") e já deixar adicionado o float no css.

Comment: Diego, boa observação, mas o menu pode ser escondido para aparecer com um clique em um icone. Assim seria feito uma grande mudança de visual e espaço. OBS: nunca fiz, mas imagino que seja assim

Answer (score -2):

Adicione float: left nas li.

E com jQuery tenha o seguinte codigo:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.top-menu li').css("width", ($('.top-menu ul').width() / $('.top-menu ul li').size()) + "px");

        $( window ).resize(function() {
            $('.top-menu li').css("width", ($('.top-menu ul').width() / $('.top-menu ul li').size()) + "px");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Mas acho que a melhor forma é a que o @DiegoLopesLima citou com css

```
display:table-cell;
```

nas li.

Answer (score -3):

```css
.top-menu ul {
  width: 100%;
}

.top-menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

.top-menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu full">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Aqui!</a></li>
    <li><a>Alí!</a></li>
    <li><a>Acolá!</a></li>
    <li><a>Mais Pra lá</a></li>
    <li><a>Não sei onde</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```