# Deixar opções no tamanho do total do menu

Tags: css

Estou tentando deixar as opções de um menu que tenho distribuídas de acordo com o tamanho total do menu, estive tentando algumas possibilidades, inclusive em um [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4435/como-deixar-todos-os-itens-de-um-menu-com-tamanho-igual-independente-da-quantida) aqui mesmo, mas sem sucesso.

O site que tenho como tomada de exemplo é esse:
[Site Exemplo](http://topdeia.com.br/perpetuare/)

O meu código está assim:

```
        <div class="col-md-8"> 
      <!-- NAVEGAÇÃO PRINCIPAL -->
      <div class="flexnav-menu-button" id="flexnav-menu-button">Menu</div>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills flexnav" id="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800" name="flexnav">
          <li><a href="index.php">INÍCIO</a></li>
          <li><a href="missao.php">MISSÃO E VISÃO</a></li>
          <li><a href="equipe.php">QUEM SOMOS </a></li>
          <li><a href="treinamentos.php">TREINAMENTOS</a></li>
          <li><a href="eventos.php">EVENTOS</a></li>
          <li><a href="contato.php">CONTATOS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- FIM NAVEGAÇÃO --> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

O `css`:

```
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  display:table-cell;
}
.nav > li > a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.nav-pills > li {
  float: left;
}
.nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

Umas das minhas tentativas foi dar `display: table;` ao ul e `display:table-cell;` ao li, mas não consegui, infelizmente o site ainda não está no ar, mas o que tenho localmente pode ser visto por essa imagem:

[image: Site em Desenvolvimento]

Comment: Olá @renan, esse site é uma imagem, um layout estático que me foi passado pelo designer.

Comment: você deseja que fique assim? https://jsfiddle.net/0k51c1nt/6/embedded/result/

Comment: Olá @SamirBraga, obrigado pela sugestão e dica, me ajudaram a entender o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver seguindo as orientações desse site: [http://www.sitepoint.com/](http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-fluid-width-variable-item-navigation-css/)

As configurações aplicadas ao meu exemplo foram essas:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #113066;
}

nav ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 16.6667%; /* fallback for non-calc() browsers */
    width: calc(100% / 6);
}
```

O código que estava assim:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
```

Ficou assim:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

No exemplo acima foi utilizado calc() com percentuais para seis colunas para obter um resultado otimizado, obrigado a todos pelas dicas.

Answer (score -1):

O seu CSS deve ser assim:

```
ul {

    display:flex;    
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content:space-between;    
}

li {

    flex-grow:1; /* SE PREFERIR TENTE ISSO TAMBÉM*/
}
```

Veja um exemplo em: http://codepen.io/colombe/pen/ezmjXq